# How to find a file and get the path using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have some folder, the total of the folder is always different. Each folder has two file named as "ID" and "ID_DONE", for the file "ID_DONE" generate by other process. I want to remove file "ID" once "ID_DONE" generate to each folder. 
I tried this, but I can not remove the "ID" file if I have more than one folder to check.
Anyone can help, please.

```
if(Test-Path -Path "$OpJob_Path\*\ID_DON"){
$Path_ID_DON = Get-ChildItem -Path "$OpJob_Path\*\ID_DON"
$Split = Split-Path -Path $Path_ID_DON
$Split
    if(Test-Path -Path "$Split\ID")
    {
        Write-Host "Remove"
        Remove-Item -Path "$Split\ID"

    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Not Found"
    }
}
else{
    Write-Host "Continue..........."
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're matching files *across multiple directories* with wildcard expression `"$OpJob_Path\*\ID_DON"`, `$Path_ID_DON` will likely contain an *array* of files (`[System.IO.FileSystem]` items).

Therefore,

```
$Split = Split-Path -Path $Path_ID_DON
```

results in `$Split` containing an *array* of the *parent-directory paths* of the files stored in `$Path_ID_DON`.

If you want to remove a file named `ID` from all these directories, if present, use the following:

```
$Split | ForEach-Object { 
  $file = Join-Path $_ 'ID'
  if (Test-Path $file) { Remove-Item $file -WhatIf }
}
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the operation. Remove it once you're sure it will do what you want.</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SBR.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
Get-ChildItem "$OpJob_Path" -File -Filter "ID_DON" -Recurse | %{Remove-Item "$($_.DirectoryName)\ID" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
```